# How to show overflow content as full in a div

Tags: html, css

So I have this `middle container (div)` which consists of 2 `smaller div`.
Here's the code for the `div` that wraps both `div`:

```css
.midContainer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 30vh;
    max-height: 700px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    overflow: auto;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Here's the code for `left div`:

```css
.tokenInfoBox{
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 700px;
    // padding: 20px 30px ;
    background-color: #1b1b1c;
    border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
```

Here's the code for `right div`:

```css
.ticketBox{
    width: 40%;
    height : 100%;
    background-color: #0e0304;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Have this added as well:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 1060px) { 
    .tokenInfoBox, .ticketBox { 
         width: 100%; 
    } 
}
```

So the content for the `left div` and `right div` (**both div**) display normally in big screen but overflow and overlap `div` below them in small screen. How do I wrap all the overflow content inside the `div`?
Here's the image in [bigger screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4xYB.jpg) and here's the image in [smaller screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWG01.jpg) where I have to scroll to see all content.

Comment: if you want to look for alternative easy way to achieve this functionality , i would suggest to go for bootstrap where you can use `col-7` , `col-5` as your class-name for the 2 divs and for the main div you can use `row` as class-name and it will be responsive and you can style your class as you want

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details.

Comment: use media queries: `@media only screen and (max-width: value) { .tokenInfoBox, .ticketBox { width: 100%; } }`

Comment: @GiritejaBille I have my css inside `.less` and can I still wrap css from that file inside `Container, row, col` for bootstrap?

Comment: @tacoshy Yes I have already added them inside my media queries with `width: 100%`

Comment: yes you can use custom CSS while using bootstrap. However this is not needed at all. Dont use a whole framework for an issue that you can solve with 2-4 lines of code yourself.

Comment: I didn't quite understand your doubt. can you reformulate it?

Comment: @Leo yes leo you can use your custom css even while using bootstrap , your css can overwrite the bootstrap's css so you can add any styling you want . As tocashy said , i think ,may be bootstrap will be overuse for your case, but i recommend you to go through that library as well , it has lot of responsive designs.

Comment: @LeoCavalcante Added some image for better illustration

Comment: @tacoshy Yea that's why I'm trying to solve this problem without using any other framework but every solution I found on SO does not solve my issue

Comment: Oooh, i got it... that's because your midContainer, that has preset height and max height. you need to remove the absolute height... will answer it in a minute

Answer (score 0):

**CSS:**

```css
.midContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.tokenInfoBox {
  flex: 1 1 25rem;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #1b1b1c;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
}

.ticketBox {
  flex: 1 1 8rem;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #0e0304;
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
```

you can use `flex` in this case when applying `flex-wrap`.

Comment: Solved some issue of overlapping in `super small screen like Galaxy S5` but still have to scroll in my 15 inch laptop screen

Comment: your question is not clear what do u need, please provide an example with the question

Comment: The overflow issue where I have to scroll to see the content. The container **does not wrap the overflow content** and I want the **overllow content** to be seen fully instead of **overflow**

Answer (score 0):

If i understood well, the problem is because you have set the height of the .midContainer, try something like this:

```css
.midContainer {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.tokenInfoBox {
  width: 60%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #1b1b1c;
}

.ticketBox {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #0e0304;
  width: 40%;
}
```

this will grow you div to fit the amount of height needed.

Also think about the use of media queries, small devices would be difficult to read 2 divs side by side, maybe should be better one over another

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .midContainer {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .tokenInfoBox {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .ticketBox {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

also I strongly recommend to use [tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/)

Comment: Still have to scroll to view my overflow content.. My issue now is that all content in `left and right div` can be displayed fully in `large screen` but all those contents became **overflow** content so I have to increase the height to view all the content but how do I make a responsive `div` to display all the **overflow content**?

Comment: use media queries `@media (max-width: 768px)`